# This looks like it may be part of a building

Tags: set-identification

Can anyone help tell me what set it would belong to?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

There's only 5 sets with at least 12 of those Dark Bluish Gray Slope, Curved 2 x 1 x 1 1/3 with Recessed Stud, and only 1 has Green Dish 2 x 2 Inverted (Radar)

[10218-1](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=10218-1) Pet Shop

[image: 10218-1]

Comment: I spent a lot of time thinking those pieces were Light instead of Dark.

Comment: 10224-1 is Town Hall, not Pet Shop.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, of course. Sorry, I had spent a bizarrely long time chasing down the wrong set because of the light balance, and re-editing and re-editing and deleting commentary and then I missed one. Thanks for letting me fix it.

Answer (score 9):

This build is from [10218: Pet Shop](https://brickset.com/sets/10218-1/Pet-Shop)

[image]